# How to import redux-logger?

Tags: redux, redux-logger

I'm trying to import redux logger v.3.0.6. https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger

### Attempt 1

```
import logger from 'redux-logger';
```

error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

### Attempt 2

```
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
```

error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js' does not provide an export named 'logger'

### Attempt 3

```
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
```

error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js' does not provide an export named 'createLogger'

The third one is the one suggested on the github page. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you might want to reinstall the package. The first and third ways are valid ways to import some of the package's functions. Something is wrong with the generated dist files. Try reinstalling

Comment: Try this: const { logger } = require("redux-logger");

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it like this:

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
// ...
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger;
```

It seems `createLogger` is a default export.

Answer (score 0):

I am using like your first attempt and it is working fine,

```
import logger from "redux-logger";
```

I am also using the same version - 3.0.6 for both typings and logger itself.

```
"@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion was given to me in the error i got after installing and importing redux-logger.
the fix i found out is given below.

```
import pkg from "redux-logger";
const {createLogger}=pkg;
const logger=createLogger()
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import * as logger from "redux-logger"
const theLogger = logger.default.createLogger()

const store = createStore(
    reducer, 
    applyMiddleware(theLogger) 
)
```